# Лента новостей, как вконтакте

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Лента новостей, как вконтакте.

Цель: Вытащить 15 последних новостей, на которых подписан пользователь. Как правильно это сделать.

Как это происходит сейчас ...

в БД есть таблицы
**posts**

```
    id_post | author | text | time | attachment | saves | reposts | likes
```

**subscriptions**

```
    id_user | id_subscription
```

**users**

```
    id | name | surname ...

     $subscriptions = fetch(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE id_user = '$id'")); // получение подписок

    $all_posts_id = array();
    foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {          
        $id_subscribe = $subscription['id_subscriptions'];
        $data = fetch(mysql_query(" SELECT id_post, time
                                    FROM posts
                                    WHERE author = '$id_subscribe'"));
        array_push_array($all_posts_id,$data);
    } // получили id и time всех новостей с подписок

    usort($all_posts_id, "cmp"); //Сортировка по времени этого массива
    rsort($all_posts_id); 
    $posts_id = array_slice($all_posts_id, 0, 15);// Вырезаем 15 самых новых

    $posts = array();
    foreach($posts_id as $post_id) {
        $id_post = $post_id['id_post'];
        //echo $id_post . '</br>';
        $posts = array_merge($posts,fetch(mysql_query("SELECT *
                                    FROM posts
                                    JOIN users ON users.id =  posts.author
                                    WHERE id_post = '$id_post'")));

    } // по id делаем полные запросы в БД уже не только с id и time
```

Comment: А почему бы не сделать сортировку по времени и ограничить число записей прямо в SQL запросе ? Зачем грузить базу и пшп лишними данными ?

Comment: С учетом Ваших предыдущих двух вопросов рекомендую почитать про такие параметры SQL запроса как **ORDER BY** и **LIMIT**

Comment: если делать через ORDER BY и LIMIT, как я раньше делал, то лимит вытягивал до 15 новостей каждой подписки и в общем получалось больше 15. Поэтому я решил вытянуть все id подписок отсортировать, обрезать и потом по этим 15 вытягивать сообщения

Comment: Если Вы не можете провернуть подобные операции внутри базы данных, то Вам следует пересмотреть структуру базы данных, представьте что будет, если вдруг Ваш сайт обретет популярность на него бросится тысячи людей и количество новостей будет измеряться десятками тясяч, а Вы все эти десятки тысяч дергаете каждый раз, когда нужно выбрать всего 15.

Comment: @Zow, структуру таблиц в студию! Конечно тут нужно запрос составлять. А иначе зачем тебе БД?

Comment: posts
id_post | author | text | time | attachment | saves | reposts | likes 

subscriptions
id_user | id_subscription

users

id | name | surname ...

Comment: @Zow - sqlfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получился такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts`
WHERE
  (SELECT `subscription_status` FROM `subscriptions`
     WHERE
       `id_user` = 1
       AND
       `id_subscription` = `posts`.`author`
  LIMIT 1) = 1

ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 0,15
```

В строке `'id_user' = 1` нужно указывать ИД пользователя, которому выводишь сообщения авторов, на которых он подписан.

[Вот пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29f30/3). Структуру я упростил. И немного изменил: в таблицу `subscriptions` добавил поле `subscription_status` (0|1), которое говорит, не отписался ли участник от этого юзера.

---

Получается, твой похапе-скрипт сократился до

```
$id_user = 1;  // ИД пользователя-получателя
$page = 1;     // чтоб не было вопроса «как получить следующие 15 сообщений»
$posts_per_page = 15;   // количество сообщений на странице

$posts = fetch(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `posts`
WHERE
  (SELECT `subscription_status` FROM `subscriptions`
     WHERE
       `id_user` = '. $id_user .'
       AND
       `id_subscription` = `posts`.`author`
  LIMIT 1) = 1
ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT '. max(0, ($page-1) * $posts_per_page) .','. $posts_per_page));
```